# Google appengine task queue time limitation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

It seems that appengine's task queue has a 10min limitation, I'm wondering if there's any workaround to get large task done.
More specifically, my tasks are usually working with google cloud sql, and may go over several tables.

Answer (score 3):

The standard solution is to use [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/). You can create a separate Module with code to execute your tasks and configure it to run for as long as necessary to complete all tasks.

Comment: I assume you are suggesting to use a module of type [B](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) as a module with Automatic scaling is still bounded to a 10 min taskqueue time limit. Also, the original task could be broken to smaller tasks that take less than 10 minutes than you can use AE pipelines or Deferred tasks to help with chunking the workload.